# Не вызывается функция (js) через onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Только что искал на этом сайте ответы на этот вопрос, но безуспешно.
В чём проблема: `onclick`  в js, как известно, должен выполнять код, находящемся в этом параметре по клику на элемент.

Ок, код `onclick="id();"` выполняется правильно по клику, вот только функция `id` не находится, то есть в консоле пишет что функция отсутствует.

Вот код функции id

```js
function id() {
  localStorage.setItem("Name", document.getElementById('in1').value);
  localStorage.setItem("SurName", document.getElementById('in2').value);
  localStorage.setItem("Class", document.getElementById('in3').value);
  localStorage.setItem("School", document.getElementById('in4').value);
  localStorage.setItem("City", document.getElementById('in5').value);
  localStorage.setItem("Region", document.getElementById('in6').value);
  localStorage.setItem("Country", document.getElementById('in6').value);
}
```

```html
<section class="section_type1">
  <h2>Регистрация</h2>

  <input placeholder="Ваше имя" id="in1">
  <input placeholder="Ваша фамилия" id="in2">
  <input placeholder="Ваш класс" type="number" id="in3">
  <input placeholder="Номер вашей школы (цифра)" type="number" id="in4">
  <input placeholder="Город проживания" id="in5">
  <input placeholder="Регион / область" id="in6">
  <input placeholder="Страна" id="in7">
</section>

<section class="section_type1">
  <button onclick="id();">
    <h2 class="type1_h2">Сохранить</h2>
  </button>
  <p class="type1_p">
    Нажимая кнопку "Сохранить" вы даёте своё согласие на использование нашей
    <a onclick="open_window('Politick.html');"> политики и пользовательского соглашения </a>
  </p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не поверите но я решил просто сменить название функции в файле id.js и при её вызове в onclick, и это сработало . Сменил с id(); на identifi();

Comment: мы не верим, извини пожалуйста

Answer (score -1):

Я конечно не настаиваю, но если по кайфу копировать вставить, то пользуйся на здоровье, но циклы тоже не просто так придуманы, да и фреймфорки существуют разные, вуй посмотри пару гайдов, я не знаю

```js
const prefab = ['Name', 'SurName', 'Class', 'School', 'City', 'Region', 'Country'];

$('#btn_save').click(()=>{
    const inps = $('.section_type1 > input');
    console.log('all:', inps.length);

    // можешь цыкол заменить на forEach, чтобы тебе проще было:
    for(let [i, inp] of [...inps].entries()){
        console.log(prefab[i], inp.value || '[empty]');
        // localStorage[prefab[i]] = inp.value || '[empty]';

        // Я пользуюсь (и это удобнее):
        // localStorage.key = value;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section_type1">
    <h2>Регистрация</h2>
    
    <input placeholder="Ваше имя" id="in1">
    <input placeholder="Ваша фамилия" id="in2">
    <input placeholder="Ваш класс" type="number" id="in3">
    <input placeholder="Номер вашей школы (цифра)" type="number" id="in4">
    <input placeholder="Город проживания" id="in5">
    <input placeholder="Регион / область" id="in6">
    <input placeholder="Страна" id="in7">
    
</section>

<section class="section_type1">
    <button id="btn_save">
        <h2 class="type1_h2">Сохранить</h2>
    </button>
    <p class="type1_p">Нажимая кнопку "Сохранить" вы даёте своё согласие на использование нашей <a onclick="open_window('Politick.html');"> политики и пользовательского соглашения </a> </p>
</section>

<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="id.js"></script>
```